# Multiple forms connected to one sheet. Trying to tigger onSubmit for just one form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey everyone I am new to coding and writing script for google sheets. I could really use some help.

I have a google sheet that has multiple forms connected to it. I wrote a script to create a new folder with the persons name who submits a response to the intake form. I then made the trigger set for on submit. However, it runs anytime any form has a submission from the connected forms. I would like it to only run when one form receives a submission. I looked up trigger builder and tried to write another script for when a form is submitted. It doesn't have any errors when it runs and it does not create the new folder. Please help. Thank you!

```
function newFolder() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var names = ss.getSheetByName("Intake");
   var responseName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 2).getValue();  
   var ptFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Responses');
   var folder = ptFolder.next();
   var newFolder = folder.createFolder(responseName);
}

function onSub(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('*I put my form id in here*');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('newFolder')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Source
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder

here is the working code now

```
function newFolder(e) { 
 const sh = e.range.getSheet(); 
 if (sh.getName() ==("Intake") { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Intake"); 
  var responseName = names.getRange(names.getLastRow(), 2).getValue(); 
  var ptFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Responses'); 
  var folder = ptFolder.next(); 
  var newFolder = folder.createFolder(responseName); } }
```

Comment: Each form links to a different Sheet in the Spreadsheet therefore you can determine which form has triggered the submission by knowing which which she has received the data.  You can determine the sheet from the trigger event object  sheet = e.range.getSheet();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function newFolder(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "The Linked Sheet Name for that form") {
   //write your code in here
  }
}
```

Use the Spreadsheet onFormSubmit and get your responses from the event object.

[Form Submit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!! I have been trying to figure it out for two days.